# Perforce: deleting a p4 client with an empty changelist

Tags: perforce

Is it okay to delete a P4 workspace containing an empty changelist?

In other words, is the changelist get deleted from the server as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it out:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 -c subressors-computer change
Change 164 created.

C:\Perforce\test>p4 client -d subressors-computer
Client 'subressors-computer' has pending changes. To delete the client, delete any pending changes first. An administrator may specify -f to force the delete of another user's client.

C:\Perforce\test>p4 client -d -f subressors-computer
Client subressors-computer deleted.

C:\Perforce\test>p4 describe 164
164 - no such changelist.
```

You need `admin` permission to be able to use the `-f` flag.  If you aren't an admin, you'll need to delete your changelists yourself before deleting your client.  This is easy to script:

```
p4 -Ztag -F "change -d %change%" changes -s pending --me | p4 -x - run
```